# Handling cookies from another site

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies, youtube, youtube-api

I just wanted to ask if you can retrieve cookies in your asp.net application from when you logged into the YouTube website?

I understand how to set and retrieve cookies using .net and i could do this when the user inputs there username and password in my application but whats the point if the user has already logged into there YouTube account using YouTube. So from the user logging into there account using YouTube could i retrieve the cookies set by YouTube?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not able to read cookies from another domain since doing so would be a huge security risk. So in your case, your web app would not be able to read cookies from YouTube.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can leverage [OpenId](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/) or [OAuth](http://oauth.net/about/) for authentication and/or authorization respectively. [This](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/04/01/openid-versus-oauth-from-the-users-perspective/) is a comparison of the two.